# Run linux command while creating a envrionment variable during docker compose up

Tags: mysql, node.js, shell, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to create an environment variable dynamically, whenever the docker-compose up happens or containers get restarted automatically.

yml file:

```
web-app:
    build: .
    container_name: abc-server
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - "abc-server-data:/usr/src/app/Volumns"
    env_file:
      - ./abc.config
    environment:
      - HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=echo $(hostname -I)
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
      # - server_config
```

here I want to send HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS everytime either docker compose up or it automatically restarts

Comment: updated question, please share if u have any possible solution for same

Comment: Remove the link.

Comment: done link removed

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

To create an environment variable dynamically you need a `.env` file that should also be populated dynamically.

You can use the below command to dynamically pick your host machine's IP address.

```
echo "HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')" > .env && sudo docker-compose up
```

### Explanation

The output of `$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')` is your host machine IP address which gets pushed to your `.env` file together with the 'key' HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS.

In your yaml file you will have the below.

```
web-app:
...
    environment:
      - HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=${HOST_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}
...
```

Comment: what can we do while the containers restarted automatically and ip address of host machine is not same it won't be the correct value
Btw thanks for the response

Comment: To achieve this, you will need to write an external service that updates the host machine's IP in your .env file whenever your host IP changes. When the container restarts, it will automatically use the new IP in .env.